# Django Form validation errors handling using AJAX

Tags: python, ajax, django

Having the following form being generated in a Modal:

**Template:**

...

```
<div id="form-modal-body" class="modal-body">
            <form id="register_new_customer" method="post" action="{% url "customer:new_customer" %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div id="form-errors" class='form-errors' class="text-danger"></div>
                {%for field in customer_form %}
                    <div class="form-group {%if field.errors %} has-error{%endif%}">
                        <span class="help-block">{{ field.errors }}</span>
                        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                        <div>{{ field }}</div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

...

I'm submitting the form using AJAX as follow:

```
        $(document).on('submit', '#register_new_customer', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $('#register_new_customer')
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success:function (response) {
                // TODO: How to handle Form Validation error messages?!
            }
        })
        return false;
```

In my View I'm returning an HttpResponse in case the form is Not Valid:

```
return HttpResponse(customer_form.errors.as_json())

"phone_number": [{"message": "Please enter a valid Phone Number!", "code": "invalid"}], "box_enabled": [{"message": "This field is required.", "code": "required"}]}
```

Here I have the error messages and the correspondent Form Field:

- phone_number
- box_enabled

How can I pass this error messages correctly to the form html?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something along these lines from your view:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def phone_number_eval(request):

    if phone_number is valid:
        response = {'status': 1, 'message': "Ok"}
    else:
        response = {'status': 2, 'message': "Please enter a valid phone number."} 

    return JsonResponse(response)
```

My Javascript isn't so good, but you can do something to the effect of if `response.status` is `2`, display `message`. Maybe someone else can give the code for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already have a reply to the request in JSON format. That is fine. I would like to know if there is a generic way to retrieve the Django Form validation errors in the Form as it does without using AJAX.